# How to summarize a temporal sequence of events like this?

Tags: r, sequence

Three branches of a store, which only sells lollipops, opened on `day` 1 with empty stocks.

The history of shipments *into* each store over the first 16 days is as follows:.

```
DF = structure(list(branch.id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), day = c(3, 7, 8, 15, 3, 6, 10, 1, 5, 6, 8, 14), amount = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2)), .Names = c("branch.id", "day", "amount"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

DF

   branch.id day amount
1         1    3      1
2         1    7      2
3         1    8      2
4         1   15      3
5         2    3      3
6         2    6      2
7         2   10      5
8         3    1      2
9         3    5      4
10        3    6      1
11        3    8      2
12        3   14      2
```

In each store, at the beginning of the day, the stock may be empty; otherwise, one and only one item must be sold.

Accordingly, the remaining stock at the end of each day in each store is as follows:

```
                                       Table 2

                                        days

             1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  13  14  15  16      

branch  1    0   0   1   0   0   0   1   2   1   0   0   0   0   2   1   
        2    0   0   2   1   0   1   0   0   0   4   3   2   1   0   0 
        3    0   1   0   0   3   3   2   3   2   1   0   0   1   0   0
```

I'm also interested in the following summary, for each store, of the *continuous* periods over which the stock at the *end of the day* was *not empty*:

```
            Table 3           

branch.id  startDate endDate
1          3         3
1          7         9
1          15        16
2          3         4
2          6         6
2          10        14
3          2         2
3          5         10
3          14        14
```

**Questions:**

In fact, the actual data is huge (thousands of "branches" and thousands of days).

What are *efficient* ways to generate Table 2 and Table 3 in R?

I thought it might be useful to consider each branch's timeline as time series (?).

Comment: Please improve the title, as I couldn't come up with a better one!

Comment: This is a really interesting question but unfortunately I have not been able to solve yet!